# How to get accuracy of GPS in Android

Tags: android, gps

I need to check the accuracy of GPS... but when i use location.getAccuracy then it doesn not return me any value... Does it take time..If it takes time then how long does it takes?

Comment: The accuracy information should be available when the object is reported. Are you sure you also have lat/lon information?

Comment: Actually i need to check the strength of GPS then i need to obtain lats and Long else i will obtain Lats/long from NETWORK_PROVIDER

Comment: The `LocationManager` class provides a `getBestProvider` method. It will give you the most accurate location provider automatically. Does that resolve your issue?

Comment: Nope... Zach, I need to get coordinates from GPS only and Network Provider is my backup plan... So thats y i am finding the accuracy of GPS signals...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In android devices, mainly you can have two sources by which you can get position info : `GPS_PROVIDER` and `NETWORK_PROVIDER`

`GPS_PROVIDER` uses your GPS chipset to get a position fix. This has a greater accuracy.

`NETWORK_PROVIDER` uses the information from cell-tower to triangulate your location. Hence its accuracy is not as quite good.

You can get your accuracy info from [`Location.getAccuracy()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#getAccuracy%28%29) or from [NMEA data](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#addNmeaListener%28android.location.GpsStatus.NmeaListener%29).

> Does it take time..If it takes time then how long does it takes

Once you've started getting fixes it won't take much time. Time to first fix can be 30 seconds to 15 minutes. It depends on your GPS chipset, terrain conditions, cold/warm start etc.

To choose the best provider [read this article](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html)